# How can I fix my rt (right trigger) bottom on pso2 (Phantasy Star Online 2)

Tags: windows-10, gaming, game-controller, device-mapper, xbox-one

What happened was I was starting up pso2 and everything went okay EXCEPT for one thing. When I tried to get my items in my inventory, it highlighted everything and I can't get the item that I want. And then when I was in a mission, my right trigger (dash bottom) didn't work properly. I tried resetting my controller (Xbox One controller is what I'm using). that didn't working. I also tried collaborating my Xbox one controller into pso2 and my Windows 10. Still didn't work. And what I did last was doing the device manager way. I deleted the control device and reinstalled it in my computer again and then updated it. It was bad luck. So please, anyone! Do yall know what to do in this situation? I really love pso2 alot, and a I'm also a Twitch Streamer. I don't want to let my people down.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the drivers that the Xbox One controller uses. It can be solved by rolling back to older drivers. Unfortunately, it seems the new Xbox One chatpad and wireless receiver do not function with the old drivers.

More information can be found here:
http://www.pso-world.com/forums/showthread.php?t=229972

That should tide you over UNLESS you're using the wireless receiver and/or chatpad (like myself) in which case, we'd have to get in touch with Microsoft to change the way the triggers work, OR Sega to change the way PSO2 reads input.